# Magento 1.9 - Sign up - Cannot save the customer

Tags: magento-1.9, exception, register, mailchimp

Installed MailChimp on Magento 1.9, now the signup customer not working. It throws "Cannot save the customer".

Reviewed the exception log got the below issues.

```
2019-03-21T10:19:57+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ajaffeproduction.mailchimp_interest_group' doesn't exist
Trace: #0 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/controllers/SubscriberController.php(64): Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber->subscribe('ingewolli@hotma...')
#1 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController->newAction()
#2 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('new')
#3 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#4 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#5 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#6 /var/www/html/index.php(97): Mage::run('', 'store')
#7 {main}
```

Can anyone help us to fix this?.

Comment: Have you installed that mailchimp module correctly? Mailchimp try to save the newsletter value in this table jaffeproduction.mailchimp_interest_group... this table is not present in the database. that's the issue

Comment: Yes, installed correctly and everything working fine. But, the only issue is Customers not able to signup. Can we create this manually, any idea about their columns?.

Comment: Are you facing new error?

Comment: I think this issue is there from the MailChimp installed. As of now, we have found this major issue. Any idea on this?.

Comment: Please remove that module from the core_resource table and again reload the site.
ajaffeproduction.mailchimp_interest_group this table is already exit means it'll not create otherwise the table will be create

Comment: Will it affect the site or create any serious issues due to this?. For confirmation asking this.

Comment: Take the backup and do. I don't know how your site will react...